# chown: invalid user: ‘www–data:www-data’

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chown

I'm experiencing strage problem.
I simple need to give permissions `www-data` to a folder

```
chown -R www–data:www-data /somefolder
chown: invalid user: ‘www–data:www-data’

grep www-data /etc/passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
```

other folders generated by apache:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 16384 Jan 12 00:30 11
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data  8192 Jan 13 01:01 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data  8192 Jan 14 00:30 13
```

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5356167/1418463) and [this](http://forums.developer.mindtouch.com/showthread.php?1415-chown-www-data-invalid-user) will help.

Comment: What happens if you try to issue command without group? `chown -R www–data /somefolder`

Comment: does the user exist in /etc/shadow as well?

Comment: Weird, should work.  What happens if you use chown www-data.www-data /somefolder ?  (ie . rather then :)

Comment: @Nikolay chown: invalid user: ‘www–data’

Comment: @ernie yes, it's there as well.

Comment: I see. Very interesting... What if you try to use UID instead of username? `chown -R 33:33 /somefolder` ?

Answer (score 9):

Looking at what I assume is a copy paste:

```
chown -R www–data:www-data /somefolder
```

It should be noted that the hyphen in the user name is not a hyphen, but ASCII 150, or an en dash.  This can be verified if you copy paste the string into a tool such as http://www.asciivalue.com/.  You'll see the first dash is ASCII 150, while the second is ASCII 45.  ASCII 45 is the standard hyphen that is expected.

Fix that, and you should be fine.

Comment: This is what I was going to point out. try using `-` instead of the `–` and it might fix your problem altogether

Comment: +1. Brilliant. Difference can be seen even visually. You are very observant.

Comment: Keep getting `chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’` still

Comment: waoo... so the problem is  `-` only. rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are used to using a Debian/Ubuntu distribution and you change to a CentOS/Red Hat distribution, you may be experiencing problems because the correct user is "apache" on CentOS/Red Hat. The string becomes:

`chown -R apache:apache /somefolder`

Comment: this worked for me on Fedora 34. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what you can also **check**, is the **ID of the user** and then run it like

`chown -R 999:999 /somefolder`

this works almost each time

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here to help other users.
My linux version is CentOs6. What worked for me was.

```
chown -R nobody:nobody /home/driversn/
```

Comment: “I need to pound a nail into the wall, and I can’t find my hammer.”  /  “Well, just use a glass bottle instead — or maybe an old shoe.”  You seem to be suggesting an answer that is superficially similar to what the question is asking for, but that won’t really do the job.  If your directory is accessible to the `www-data` user after you chown it to `nobody`, it must be accessible to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

if you got error chown: invalid group: ‘www-data:wwww-data’ on

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data folder
```

does not work. solution is easy
executes those commands separately.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data folder
```

this would change the group to Apache (in Ubuntu etc os). the $USER is the current user; who is logged in.

and then

```
sudo chown -R www-data folder
```

and then this would change the user to apache.